# Select from table based on result from other table

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Firstly, this is the DB setup (Access 2010) which I didn't create and cannot change:

**Violations:**

[image: Violations]

**Packages:**

[image]

I want to select the WorkPackageCodes when the given Role1 and Role2 match a record. For example if Role1 is 3 and Role 2 is 8, I want the WorkPackageCodes with ID 3 and 8. If for example Role1 is 4 and Role2 is 6, none should be selected.

I achieved doing this with multiple queries but I want to have this in one single query (with/without subquery). So I need something where I can us IN to see if the WorkPackageID is in a resultset from the other table. I tried this:

```
//3 and 6 will be replaced by parameters
SELECT Role1 AS role FROM tblSODViolations
UNION
SELECT Role2 FROM tblSODViolations
WHERE Role1 = 3 AND Role2 = 6
```

This gives me the desired result and I tried to make one query, like this:

```
SELECT WorkPackageCode
FROM tblWorkPackages
WHERE WorkPackageID IN (SELECT Role1 AS r FROM tblSODViolations
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT Role2 FROM tblSODViolations
                        WHERE Role1 = 3 AND Role2 = 6);
```

But if I run this, I get the message:

> This operation is not allowed in subqueries.

So how can I achieve this? Or is there a way to select the WorkPackageCode in some sort of SQL if-statement? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing it as a join:

```
SELECT WorkPackageCode
FROM tblWorkPackages wp join
     tblSODViolations v
     on wp.WorkPackageID in (v.Role1, wp.WorkPackageId = v.Role2) and
        v.Role1 = 3 and v.Role2 = 6;
```

This might produce duplicates.  If so,

```
SELECT distinct WorkPackageCode
FROM tblWorkPackages wp join
     tblSODViolations v
     on wp.WorkPackageID in (v.Role1, wp.WorkPackageId = v.Role2) and
        v.Role1 = 3 and v.Role2 = 6;
```

However, it is unclear to me why this won't work:

```
SELECT WorkPackageCode
FROM tblWorkPackages wp
WHERE wp.WorkPackageID in (3, 6);
```

You can also write it like this:

```
SELECT WorkPackageCode
FROM tblWorkPackages wp
WHERE wp.WorkPackageID in (3, 6) and
      exists (select 1 from tblSODViolations where Role1 = 3 and Role2 = 6)
```

This particular version comes closest to the way you described what you need.

Comment: When using `IN (3, 6)` it works but I need the check from the other table and 3/6 are examples. In production they will be parameters.

Comment: I get `Syntax error in FROM clause` when I run either of those queries.

Comment: @Abbas . . . Sorry about that.  I left an `or` in the `in` list, as I rewrote the query.

Answer (score 1):

create the union as an inline table and use it to limit the results.

```
SELECT WorkPackageCode
FROM tblWorkPackages WP
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT Role1 AS r FROM tblSODViolations
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT Role2 FROM tblSODViolations
                        WHERE Role1 = 3 AND Role2 = 6) B 
on B.R = WP.WorkPackageID;
```

Alternatively...

```
Select workpackageCode 
FROM tblWorkPackages WP
INNER JOIN tblSODViolations V on V.WorkPackageID=WP.Role1
OR V.workPackageID=WP.Role2
WHERE V.Role1=3 and V.Role2=6
```

Comment: Your query works but the last alternative from Gordon is shortest. Thanks for the help though! ;)